# Splashscreen of PyInstaller: main window not showing on top

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, splash-screen

I'm using pyinstaller to bundle my app for Windows(OS), and added the splash screen option. After loading the main window, and closing the splashscreen, the window stays on background (behind other windows if you have any opened).
I've tried .raise_() .ActivateWindow() .setVisible(True). But they don't bring the window to the top. If I disable the splashscreen It works as it should, but I need the splash because it takes a bit to load.
I'm running out of things to try, anyone has a sugestion?

The bare minimum is the next:

```
'''
Created on Oct 17, 2022

@author: mdelu
'''
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
try:
    import pyi_splash
except:
    pass
    # print('Ejecucion en eclipse sin splash')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        if (pyi_splash.is_alive()):
            pyi_splash.close()
    except:
            pass
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = QtWidgets.QWidget(main_window)
    main_window.resize(800, 600)

    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And my *.spec file is:

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             binaries=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             noarchive=False,
             )
splash_image = 'path'
splash = Splash(splash_image,
                binaries=a.binaries,
                datas=a.datas,
                minify_script=False)
                
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          splash,
          a.scripts, 
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None)
          
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas, 
               splash.binaries,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='exe')
```

Comment: create an [mre]

Comment: thanks for your input, already have, it loads quicker so the splash is a lot less time, but it still not poping up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Using qt's splash instead

I'm using pyside6 (maybe pyqt5 have the same method). Don't use splash in pyinstaller but qt. Using win API with pyinstaller indeed against qt's cross-platform feature.

Here is my code:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QSplashScreen
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # pyside6 splash screen
    splash = QSplashScreen()
    splash.setPixmap(QPixmap(":/splash.png"))  
    splash.show()

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    # close splash screen
    splash.finish(mainWindow)
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The ":/splash.png" is defined by pyside6-rcc for cross-platform use.

**(2)** The right mathod to use pyinstaller

Only worked in single file mode.

I try again and the code below worked:
Add a new Load_Splash.py file

```py
import pyi_splash

pyi_splash.update_text('loaded...')   
# https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced-topics.html#module-pyi_splash

pyi_splash.close()
```

Then import it in main.py at the end of other imports.

```py
import Load_Splash.py
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did, but notice that I have my splash screen set so that it is not always topmost. I have not tested that in that case, and this method probably will not work in that case, but it may help you figure something out.

The way it works is that the pyinstaller splash screen is created in the process with a name of 'tk', so you can enumerate all the windows searching for 'tk' in your own process. The splash screen is created in a different thread fromyour main application.

The behaviour of this code is:

- Run the application and the splash screen is not topmost, so you can switch easily to other applications.
- When the application runs it will move it's own window in front of the splash screen and close the splash screen, remaining in that place in the Z order.
- If the splash screen was the active window then the application window becomes active.
- If the splash screen was not active (e.g. you switched to another application while this one was loading) then the application taskbar entry will flash.

Python main code (it's copy and pasted from my real application, I can't easily extract the minimal code just now):

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import win32api
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32process
import platform
import importlib
from ui_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

pyi_splash_spec = importlib.util.find_spec("pyi_splash")
if pyi_splash_spec is not None:
    import pyi_splash


# Simple data class for storing our process ID and the found splash window handle.
class EnumWindowHandlerContext:
    processId: int
    splashHWnd: int


#
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    #
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx: EnumWindowHandlerContext):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        # Get process and name of window
        (threadId, processId) = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
        n = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)

        # If our process and called 'tk' assume it is the splash window and store the handle
        if (processId == ctx.processId) and (n == 'tk'):
            ctx.splashHWnd = hwnd


def MoveAboveSplash(hwnd):
    enumContext = EnumWindowHandlerContext()
    enumContext.processId = win32api.GetCurrentProcessId()

    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, enumContext)
    if enumContext.splashHWnd != 0:
        if win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() == enumContext.splashHWnd:
            flags = win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE
        else:
            flags = win32con.SWP_NOACTIVATE | win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE

        # Move our window so it is immediately after the splash window.
        # Activate if splash was foreground, otherwise not.
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(hwnd, enumContext.splashHWnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, flags)

        # Now move the splash window so that it is behind the main window.
        # Always "no activate", we don't want to reactivate the splash screen.
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(enumContext.splashHWnd, hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, win32con.SWP_NOACTIVATE | win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE)

        # Make ourselves the foreground window. Throws an exception if it fails
        # but failure is just that it won't do it, not an error condition, so
        # ignore the exception.
        try:
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
        except:
            pass


#
def main():
    QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #app.setStyle('WindowsVista')

    mainWindow = MyMainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()

    if pyi_splash_spec is not None and pyi_splash.is_alive():
        if platform.system() == 'Windows':
            MoveAboveSplash(mainWindow.winId())

        pyi_splash.close()

    app.exec()

#
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
```

spec file for pyinstaller:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['MyApp/minimal.py'],
    pathex=['MyApp'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=['sqlite', 'tbb'],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
splash = Splash(
    'splash.png',
    binaries=a.binaries,
    datas=a.datas,
    text_pos=None,
    text_size=12,
    minify_script=True,
    always_on_top=False,
)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    splash,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='MyApp',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    splash.binaries,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='MyApp',
)
```